# Matplotlib Basemap animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.3, matplotlib-basemap

I'm using basemap to plot some points on a map, and I want to add any kind of animation to it. It could literally serve no purpose at all, as long as it is an animation it would be nice.

This is what I currently have to make the map,

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation
map = Basemap(projection='robin', resolution = 'l', area_thresh = 1000.0,
          lat_0=0, lon_0=-130)
map.drawcoastlines()
map.drawcountries()
map.fillcontinents(color = 'gray')
map.drawmapboundary()
map.drawmeridians(np.arange(0, 360, 30))
map.drawparallels(np.arange(-90, 90, 30))

x,y = map(lons, lats)
map.plot(x, y, 'ro', markersize=4)


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reworked some code from [here](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/) to fit

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation
my_map = Basemap(projection='robin', resolution = 'l', area_thresh = 1000.0,
          lat_0=0, lon_0=-130)
my_map.drawcoastlines()
my_map.drawcountries()
my_map.fillcontinents(color = 'gray')
my_map.drawmapboundary()
my_map.drawmeridians(np.arange(0, 360, 30))
my_map.drawparallels(np.arange(-90, 90, 30))

x,y = my_map(0, 0)
point = my_map.plot(x, y, 'ro', markersize=5)[0]

def init():
    point.set_data([], [])
    return point,

# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    lons, lats =  np.random.random_integers(-130, 130, 2)
    x, y = my_map(lons, lats)
    point.set_data(x, y)
    return point,

# call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=20, interval=500, blit=True)

plt.show()
```